# Converting Geographic Format in R - Central lat/lon plus meter displacement in large area

Tags: r, projection, geo

I'm working with a data-set of FSA boundary files provided by Statistics Canada. [Data and full details available here, 2016 set.](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/catalogue/92-179-X)

To make the data compatible with the rest of what I'm working on I need to convert from the provided format to lat/lon.

The details of the provided format are:

- Projection: Lambert conformal conic
- False easting: 6200000.000000
- False northing: 3000000.000000
- Central meridian: -91.866667
- Standard parallel 1: 49.000000
- Standard parallel 2: 77.000000
- Latitude of origin: 63.390675
- Linear unit: metre (1.000000)
- Datum: North American 1983 (NAD83)
- Prime meridian: Greenwich
- Angular unit: degree
- Spheroid: GRS 1980

I use rgeos::gCentroid to get the centroid of each FSA, so the solution does not need to take sf or sp objects into account.

The FSAs of greatest interest are all fairly distant from the centre lat/lon of 63.390674, -91.8666667, so approximations appropriate for short distances do not work for me.

From the solution detailed [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=108733) I adapted the following code:

```
# Read Shape File
fsa <- sf::st_read('~/lfsa000b16a_e.shp')

# Compute Centroid per FSA and store in dataframe
fsa_centroids = gCentroid(as(fsa, 'Spatial'), byid = TRUE, id = fsa$CFSAUID)
fsa_df <- data.frame(fsa_centroids)
fsa_df['fsa'] = rownames(fsa_df)

# Earth Radius
R = 6371007.1810

# Central Lat/Lon
lat0 = 63.390675
lon0 = -91.866667

# Remove false Easting/Northing
fsa_df$x = fsa_df$x - 6200000
fsa_df$y = fsa_df$y - 3000000

# Sphere-approximation calculations
fsa_df$lat = asin(sin(lat0*pi/180)*cos(fsa_df$y/R) + cos(lat0*pi/180)*sin(fsa_df$y/R)*cos(0)) * 180/pi
fsa_df$lon = lon0 + atan2(sin(pi/2)*sin(fsa_df$x/R*cos(fsa_df$lat*pi/180)), cos(fsa_df$x/R)-sin(fsa_df$lat*pi/180)^2) * 180/pi
```

(apologies with nonsense terms like `cos(0)`, I wanted to keep the full formula present and I was uncertain what bearing was 0 rad, so I was tinkering)

My problem is twofold: This solution is based on a perfect sphere assumption and the data uses the GRS 1980 spheroid. Additionally, since we are traversing a spheroid, the order in which you go east/west and north/south matters (though both orders have very high errors in the approximate solution).

Is there an easier way or libraries I can leverage to do this conversion?